# Embedded WebResource and FileStream

Tags: asp.net

```
[assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("Project.ConfigurationFiles.Tools.xml", "text/xml")]




 string resource = "Project.ConfigurationFiles.Tools.xml";
 string pathXML =Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(this.GetType(), resource);

 XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ToolB));
 using (FileStream myFileStream = new FileStream(pathXML, FileMode.Open))
{
```

The error I get:

> Illegal characters in path.

I guess this happens because FilleStream need file and not url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception occurs because [GetWebResourceUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.getwebresourceurl.aspx) function returns an HTTP address but [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) expects a file path. From your code snippet I suppose you are trying to read the XML file that's embedded into the assembly and deserialize it back to an object. Here's how you could achieve this:

```
var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var resource = "Project.ConfigurationFiles.Tools.xml";
using (var stream = executingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resource))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ToolB));
    var toolB = (ToolB)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
}
```